# How to enter the root PID namespace from a distribution installed on WSL?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, windows, namespace

I've been experimenting with the Windows Subsystem for Linux v2 (WSL 2) and read in their FAQ that all distributions are installed on the same virtual machine (VM), isolated using namespaces, in Hyper-V. This can be confirmed by starting Ubuntu and Debian, and the running the following command to view the list of active VMs:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> hcsdiag list
8B389621-7C83-484C-8F24-5CAEDA29AA49
    VM,                         Running, 8B389621-7C83-484C-8F24-5CAEDA29AA49, WSL
```

If these distributions are isolated by namespaces, why can't enter the same root namespace from both
distributions using `nsenter`?

These are the processes running in e.g. the Ubuntu distribution, which has `/init` as PID 1:

```
root@DESKTOP-5VNI36Q:~# ps -Af
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 14:05 ?        00:00:00 /init
root         7     1  0 14:05 ?        00:00:00 /init
root         8     7  0 14:05 ?        00:00:00 /init
nlykkei      9     8  0 14:05 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root        52     9  0 14:06 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo su -
root        53    52  0 14:06 pts/0    00:00:00 su -
root        54    53  0 14:06 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root        70    54  0 14:06 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -Af
```

If I enter all namespaces of PID 1 from e.g. the Ubuntu distribution, then I'm stuck in the same PID namespace as I originated, and cannot proceed further (see below):

```
root@DESKTOP-5VNI36Q:~# nsenter-t1 -a
```

Conversely, if I enter all namespaces of PID 1 from the Debian distribution, then I cannot proceed further either, and is stuck in the same PID namespace as I originated. Also, the PID namespace is different from the Ubuntu PID namespace.

**Ubuntu** distribution:

```
root@DESKTOP-5VNI36Q:~# ls -la /proc/self/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 cgroup -> 'cgroup:[4026531835]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 ipc -> 'ipc:[4026532188]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 mnt -> 'mnt:[4026532186]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 net -> 'net:[4026531992]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 pid -> 'pid:[4026532189]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 pid_for_children -> 'pid:[4026532189]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 user -> 'user:[4026531837]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 uts -> 'uts:[4026532187]'
root@DESKTOP-5VNI36Q:~# ls -la /proc/1/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 root root 0 Oct 20 14:05 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root 0 Oct 20 14:05 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 cgroup -> 'cgroup:[4026531835]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 ipc -> 'ipc:[4026532188]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:05 mnt -> 'mnt:[4026532186]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 net -> 'net:[4026531992]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 pid -> 'pid:[4026532189]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 pid_for_children -> 'pid:[4026532189]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 user -> 'user:[4026531837]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:06 uts -> 'uts:[4026532187]'
```

**Debian** distribution:

```
root@DESKTOP-5VNI36Q:~# ls -la /proc/self/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 cgroup -> 'cgroup:[4026531835]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 ipc -> 'ipc:[4026532203]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 mnt -> 'mnt:[4026532211]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 net -> 'net:[4026531992]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 pid -> 'pid:[4026532204]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 pid_for_children -> 'pid:[4026532204]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 user -> 'user:[4026531837]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 uts -> 'uts:[4026532202]'
root@DESKTOP-5VNI36Q:~# ls -la /proc/1/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 root root 0 Oct 20 12:04 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root 0 Oct 20 11:17 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 12:04 cgroup -> 'cgroup:[4026531835]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 12:04 ipc -> 'ipc:[4026532203]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 12:04 mnt -> 'mnt:[4026532201]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 12:04 net -> 'net:[4026531992]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 12:04 pid -> 'pid:[4026532204]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 14:10 pid_for_children -> 'pid:[4026532204]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 12:04 user -> 'user:[4026531837]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 12:04 uts -> 'uts:[4026532202]'
```

Comment: You can't enter the root namespace from another namespace. That's a fundamental property of namespaces: you can only enter a namespace from itself or one of its parents, and in particular you can't enter a namespace from one of its children. If there's a way to start a process in the root namespace, it can't be from within the Ubuntu instance or within the Debian instance. `nsenter -t1 -p` just enters the namespace that you're already in.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - But, check `/proc/self/ns` and `/proc/1/ns` of the Debian distribution. The mount namespace is `4026532211` and `4026532201`. I can actually enter the mount namespace of `init` using `nsenter -t1 -p` in this case. Does your statement only applies to user and PID namespaces?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - Isn't it more correctly to say "ancestors" and "descendants" instead of "parents" and "children"? Namespaces are always structured in a tree, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, I meant ancestors and descendants. And I was talking about pid namespaces. When you run `nsenter -t1 -p` from Debian, you enter the PID namespace of Debian's init, which is a no-op since you were already in that PID namespace. But `nsenter -t1 -m` can do something useful.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - Thank you. So, in order to spawn a process in the root PID namespace, you must have some process already in the root PID namespace execute a program? I'm only interested, since Microsoft wrote in their documentation something like: "*experienced Linux users will be able to break this namespace isolation*".

Comment: Yes, in order to spawn a process in a namespace, you must have a process in that namespace or one of its ancestors. For the root namespace, you need to be already in the root namespace. This doesn't rule out breaking out indirectly, for example by writing to a file which a process in the root namespace will pick up and execute (e.g. if `cron` is running in the root namespace and a process in another namespace can write to `/etc/crontab`).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - Are their other namespace types other than mount that allows for joining an ancestor namespace, i.e. going back up the namespace hierarchy using e.g. `nsenter`?

Comment: I'm sure there are. I don't know much about Linux namespaces, but I suspect that if you don't isolate all of them, breaking out is possible on a typical system. If you want isolation of potentially hostile software, you need a container, not just a namespace.

Comment: @Shuzheng PID and user namespaces are hierarchical, while mount namespaces are flat. PID and user namespaces have more restricted rules and you basically cannot switch into a parent PID or user namespace, even if you manage to get a reference to them. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html